# MongoDb: How to unset attribute from nested arrays?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to remove an attribute from a triple-nested array without success. Here is an example of the data I want to remove:

```
Controls: [
    {    
        Name: 'ControlNumberOne',
        Submit: {   
            Executes: [
                {
                    Name: 'execute',
                    Type: 0
                },
                {
                    Name: 'anotherExecute',
                    Type: 0
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {    
        Name: 'ControlNumberTwo',
        Submit: {   
            Executes: [
                {
                    Name: 'anotherFromAnotherControl',
                    Type: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }

]
```

I tried the following update queries but none of them worked:

- `db.Page.update('Controls.Submit.Executes.Type': { $exists : true } }, { $unset : { 'Controls.Submit.Executes.Type' : 1 } }, false, true);)`
- `db.Page.update('Controls.Submit.Executes.Type': { $exists : true } }, { $unset : { 'Controls.$.Submit.Executes.$.Type' : 1 } }, false, true);)`

However, if I execute `db.Page.find('Controls.Submit.Executes.Type': { $exists : true } })` it does return all the Executes that still have a Type attribute.

Can this be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Your `Executes` seems to be an object, not an array.

Comment: you're right I mispelled it... please take a look at it now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for an answer (like me), here it is.

With MongoDB version 3.6+, it is now possible to use the positional operator to update all items in an array, including the deeper nested level. See [official documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/).:

```
db.getCollection('xxx').update(
   {'Controls.Submit.Executes.Type': { $exists : true },
   { $unset : {'Controls.$[].Submit.Executes.$[].Type' : 1}}
)
```

This code is tested and works well with MongoDB CLI, RoboMongo and Mongo-Java driver.

Answer (score 5):

Querying and updating of nested arrays is not (yet) supported by MongoDB commands directly, this has to be done on the client side:

- read the document into a variable
- manipulate the array
- update the document, rewriting the entire array

See this issue on Jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 and this thread on stackoverflow: [Mongo update of subdocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236322/mongo-update-of-subdocs)

Given your example, this would look like this:

```
db.xx.find(
    {'Controls.Submit.Executes.Type': { $exists : true } }
).forEach( function(doc) {
    doc.Controls.forEach( function(c) {
        c.Submit.Executes.forEach( function(e) {
            if ( e.Type != undefined ) delete e.Type;        
        });
    });
    db.xx.update({_id: doc._id},{$set:{Controls:doc.Controls}});
});
```

and the result is:

```
> db.xx.findOne()
{
    "Controls" : [
        {
            "Name" : "ControlNumberOne",
            "Submit" : {
                "Executes" : [
                    {
                        "Name" : "execute"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name" : "anotherExecute"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Name" : "ControlNumberTwo",
            "Submit" : {
                "Executes" : [
                    {
                        "Name" : "anotherFromAnotherControl"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "_id" : ObjectId("5159ff312ee0f7d445b03f32")
}
```